# Python default arguments and argument names

Tags: python

I was wondering if the 'a=a', and 'b=b' can lead to problems/unexpected behaviour? code works fine in the example.

```
def add_func(a=2,b=3):
   return a+b

a=4
b=5
answer = add_func(a=a, b=b)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not that I know of, although I'd love to be proved wrong.

The formal language reference defines [the lexical structure of a function call](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#calls). The important bit is that it defines a "keyword_item" as `identifier "=" expression`. Also, here's what it says about how the arguments to the call are interpreted:

> If keyword arguments are present, they are first converted to
>   positional arguments, as follows. First, a list of unfilled slots is
>   created for the formal parameters. If there are N positional
>   arguments, they are placed in the first N slots. Next, for each
>   keyword argument, the identifier is used to determine the
>   corresponding slot (if the identifier is the same as the first formal
>   parameter name, the first slot is used, and so on). If the slot is
>   already filled, a TypeError exception is raised. Otherwise, the value
>   of the argument is placed in the slot, filling it (even if the
>   expression is None, it fills the slot). When all arguments have been
>   processed, the slots that are still unfilled are filled with the
>   corresponding default value from the function definition.

This lists a few possible scenarios.

In the simple case, like you mentioned, where there are two formal arguments (`a` and `b`), and if you specify the function call using keyword parameters like `add_func(a=a, b=b)`, here's what happens:

1. Two slots are created to hold the parameters.
2. Since you didn't provide any positional arguments in the call (just keyword arguments), none of the slots are filled initially.
3. Each of your keyword arguments are analyzed individually, and the **identifier** of your argument (the "a" in the `a=` part) is compared with all of the formal parameters names of the function (the names that were given the parameters when the function was defined, in our case, `a` and `b`).
4. When a match occurs, the **value** of the keyword arguments (in this case, `4`!) is used to fill the corresponding slot.
5. This repeats until all keyword arguments are analyzed. If all slots aren't filled, then Python tries to assign a default value to the remaining slots if one exists. If not, an error is raised.

So, Python treats the "identifier" in a keyword argument completely differently. This is only true for keyword arguments, though; obviously, if you tried something like `add_func(b, a)`, even though your parameters themselves are called `b` and `a`, this would *not* be mapped to the formal parameters in the function; your parameters would be backwards. However, `add_func(b=b, a=a)` works fine; the positions don't matter as long as they are keyword arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I've got into the habit of using the 'a=a' just so I can keep the same descriptive names for various things - good to know I don't have to go back over all the code and change it!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether or not the global objects pointed to are mutable or immutable. immutable objects such as your integers are copies when modified, so it's safe. Mutable objects such as lists are modified in-place, and are NOT safe to use this way. Any change to them persists between calls and may (and probably will) cause unexpected behaviors.

This:

```
a=[]
def f(a=a):
    pass
```

Is the same as:

```
def f(a=[]):
    pass
```

Which is a known bad practice in Python programs.

Comment: And the important note here, I think, (which isn't really related to using `a=a` in the **function call**) is that [default parameters are evaluated _once_, when the function is defined](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#function).

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out - I'm sure this has burned quite a few people.

Comment: @user986065: Yes, in cases like these, it's generally recommended to use a placeholder value (usually `None`) as the default, and then check for it in the body of the function (e.g. `if a is None: a = []`).

Comment: This completely misses the point of the question, which is about *calling* a function, not defining it.

Comment: @EthanFurman You are mistaken. Show me where it says it's about calling only, consider also that it has a def (short for "define") in it? This is also useful info whether he asked for it or not.